# Post multiple entities using AngularJS services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to post 2 entities using Angular JS .

here is my AccountController.js

```
 $scope.InsertAccount = function (user,account) {
        accountsService.InsertAccount(user,account);

    };
```

My AccountService.js

```
 var InsertAccount = function (user, account) {

        return $http.post("http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV", {user :user, compte: account})
        .then(function () {
            $log.info("Insert Successful");
            return;
        });
    };
```

I can post a single parameter ,but it doesnt work when i try to put many.

Comment: What do you mean by `post a single parameter` ? I can't see any parameters involved.

Comment: i mean when i post a user it works but when i try to post user and account using one route it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean many users, many accounts? Typically, since you're creating multiple entities, you'll want multiple POSTs. So a helper function could be what you're looking for:

```
$scope.InsertAccounts = function (users, accounts) {
  return $q.all(users.map(function (user, n) {
    return $scope.InsertAccount(user, accounts[n]);
  }));
}
```

Comment: I dont mean many users, i want to post one user with his account using one route

Comment: What error are you seeing. This is likely a backend issue. Can you post the backend code for this route?

Answer (score 0):

should be work your method. however can try this one

```
var InsertAccount = function (user, account) {
    var data = {user :user, compte: account}; // assign first and can try JSON.stringify({,,})
    return $http.post("http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV", data)
      .then(function (response) {
         $log.info("Insert Successful");
         return response;
    });
};
```

in server side can try

```
public HttpResponseMessage addUserV(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);
    var user = result.user;
    var compte = result.compte;
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: when we retrieve the JSonObject in webApi Controller , how can we deserialize it ? it seems that the problem is in this code                                    
                                                                     addUserV(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
        {
            Utilisateur user = data["user"].ToObject<Utilisateur>();
            Compte compte = data["compte"].ToObject<Compte>();

           ...}

Comment: same process can use that you previously used. what technology used in server side?

Comment: can try using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` @IkramBk

Answer (score 0):

try using `JSON.stringify()`, The `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string. so it will consider your array/object as a single value.

```
 var InsertAccount = function (user, account) {
 //use JSON.stringify
 var data = JSON.stringify({user :user, compte: account});

 return $http.post("http://localhost:26309/api/Compte/addUserV", data)
  .then(function (response) {
     $log.info("Insert Successful");
     return response;
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

when we retrieve the JSonObject in webApi Controller , how can we deserialize it ? it seems that the problem is in this code `

```
    public HttpResponseMessage addUserV(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject data)
    {
        Utilisateur user = data["user"].ToObject<Utilisateur>();
        Compte compte = data["compte"].ToObject<Compte>();

        try
        {
            if (!_compteService.CreerUtilisateur(user, compte))
            {
                throw new Exception("ajout de l'instance de l'utilisateur non effecuté " + compte.designation);
            }
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            //response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created;
            // String uri = Url.Link("GetUser", new { id = user.id });
            // response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);

            return response;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);

            return response;
        }
    }
```

`